# Calculate Gaussian wave

Tags: wave-equation, gaussian-elimination

I'm told that $\Psi(x,0)$ is built out of plane waves according to the amplitude distribution function $$a(k) = (C\alpha/\pi^.5)e^{-\alpha^2k^2}$$

How do I calculate $\psi(x,t)$?

Comment: What is $\psi$? The solution to the wave equation?

Comment: What kind of dispersion relation you have?  For example, Schrödinger wave equation: $$\omega(k)=\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}$$